# Android wear project not syncing app with wearble

Tags: wear-os

I have an Android Studio project that has both a wear and mobile module.  I am installing to a physical handheld device connected via usb that is connected to a wearable emulator.  Bothe the wearable emulator and the handheld device say they are in fact connected, but when i build my project to the handheld device it doesn't show the app in the "start.." menu on the wearable.

I am not sure if i have to install it manually on the wearable or not.  It would seem to me that the project should automatically install both if i build to the handheld.

Anyone have experience with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/creating.html has some useful info

Make sure you're forwarding adb to the emulator by using this adb command:

```
adb -d forward tcp:5601 tcp:5601
```

You also need to deploy the app you're debugging separately to the emulated wearable. Every Android wear project has two modules. Mobile goes to the phone or tablet, wear to the watch. You need to deploy the mobile apk to the phone and the wear apk to the watch.

Under the run menu, selecting debug should allow you to choose witch module you build, select wear then pick your emulated environment when it asks your target